# How does the change in temperature of water in a tube depend on the angle that the tube makes with the gravitational field/the horizontal?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, heat-conduction

Let's imagine a tube that is open at one end and is filled with water. A constant source of heat is applied to a specific spot somewhere at the middle of the tube, for a example a preheated soldering iron of constant temperature. Let's say you measure the temperature of water at the upper end of the tube over a specific amount of time when the tube is parallel to the gravitational force, or 90 degrees to the horizontal. If you keep all the conditions constant, including the amount of time for heating, but change the angle so that it is 80 degrees to the horizontal, then 70, 60 and so on... You will find that the increase in the temperature becomes less as the angle decreases. But what would the graph of the increase in temperature vs sine of the angle look like? And what is the theory behind it? I undertstand that there are convection currents of natural convection caused by a buoyant force, which is caused by the difference in density and which will be counteracted by a normal force of reaction as the the tube becomes tilted. However, I would like to understand more of the physics involved in order to model the phenomenon.

The following graphs are based on primary data (collected by me). The tube used was a burette, the mark of 17 ml was in between the mark of 1 ml and the source of heat, which was at the mark of 25 ml. I realized that the wire of the thermometer at the mark of 17 ml could pose a confounding variable as it was curved, so it was not used in the fourth measurement session. There are some pictures of the apparatus below the graphs.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hard to predict. The temperature increase is mainly due to natural convection, and the rate of convection will depend on the temperature difference, various properties of the liquid and, unfortunately, the diameter of the tube, as well as its angle. These factors will not act independently. Can you try the experiment?

Comment: @PhilipWood I have added some graphs based on first-hand data

Comment: You can fit a 3rd order (or higher) polynomial through your data, but getting a "1st principles" equation is going to be a daunting task.

Comment: @PhilipWood Could you please give some sources that deal with those factors?

Comment: I'm sorry; I have no sources; I just recognise that the convection is driven by expansion of the heated liquid and involves hot liquid flowing in the upward-slanting direction and cooler liquid in the downward-slanting direction, the flows being confined by the tube walls and probably involving turbulent mixing of the hot and the cold. This is a daunting problem (for me at least) in fluid dynamics. But I applaud your experimental skills.

Comment: @DavidWhite Could you maybe refer to any literature relevant to the question?

Comment: @Alimp777, I've never seen this type of problem before, so I'm not familiar with literature that would describe your problem.  I expect the temperature will be a function of both conduction and convection, with the rate of heat transfer of each being a function of angle.  I do have several questions:  1) What is the material of the tube?   2) What is the tube diameter and tube wall thickness?  3) If the tube is open at one end, how do you keep water from spilling out of it when it is horizontal?  4) What is the temperature of the heating element?  continued in next "block"

Comment: 5) Do you know the area of the heating element in contact with the tube?  6) Are you measuring water temperature at only one spot or do you have a way to measure the temperature at several spots at the same time as you are heating the water?  7) Do you have a way of putting tiny "tracers" in the water so you can see how much convection you are getting?  8) Why did you measure temperature at the very particular points that you noted in your query?  9) You went through a lot of trouble to gather your data.  Is there a particular application that you have in mind?

Comment: @DavidWhite 1) Glass.  2) The diameter is about 1.1 cm. I cannot measure the thickness, the wall is thin.  3) If you look at the graphs you can see that the minimum sine value is about 0.2, so it was not perfectly horizontal (by the way, I have added one more graph)   4) I would say 300 ± 50 °C. I am not sure about the uncertainty, I could not determine the temperature by a direct measurement. - continued.

Comment: @DavidWhite 5) This is a weakness of my method. I tried to make the rod of the soldering iron always be perpendicular to the burette just by looking, in order to control for the contact area, but a even slight tilt of the soldering iron with respect to the tube from one trial to the next, I assume, will make a significant difference in the temperature change. The diameter of the rod is a little bit greater. I cannot measure it at the moment. 6) I have editted the text, see the last paragraph in particular for this question. 7) What kind of "tracers"?  - continued

Comment: @DavidWhite 8) The point at the mark of 1 ml is obvious since it is at the water-air boundary. I will now add some pictures of the apparatus. - continued

Comment: @DavidWhite 9) The whole trouble is called International Baccalaureate Diploma Programme (IB DP). This is the topic of my Extended Essay. In a subject guide it says: "Before embarking on experimental work, students must first ensure that there is scope to explore and model the physics that underpins it. A purely empirical investigation that relates a number of variables in the absence of any theoretical foundation is never satisfactory.", but I did not read that carefully, so here I am.

Comment: @Alimp777, the tracers would be very small bits of something that is neutrally buoyant so you can see if there is convection.  The physics: heat conduction through the glass; heat conduction and convection in the water column; buoyancy of heated water; probably laminar flow of heated water as it rises up the tube.  This is a difficult problem (which I'm sure that you are now aware of).  If you have the chance to choose a simpler problem, I would suggest that you do so.

Comment: @DavidWhite Hi! What about the heat transfer to the lower end of the tube, that is, below the source of heat? I think that there would be no convection but only conduction through the glass and water. I woud like to know the relative contribution of the conduction through the glass to the heat transfer. I know that the conductivity of glass is a bit higher than that of water (0.8 to 0.6), but the area perpendicular to the heat transfer of water is way more larger than that of the glass.

Comment: @DavidWhite And I don't know whether I can apply the eqaution from this page: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/heatra.html#c2 since it seems to be for the heat transfer within one material only.

Comment: @DavidWhite Is Fourier's law applicable in this case?

Comment: @Alimp777, I don't know.